# k8s - use two siblings helm charts with common data and dynamic variables in values yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm 3 with k8s, with two siblings charts on root folder: `<my-folder>/<chart-1>` and `<my-folder>/<chart-2>`.

The kubectl version:

> Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21",
> GitVersion:"v1.21.6",
> GitCommit:"d921bc6d1810da51177fbd0ed61dc811c5228097",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T17:50:34Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"} Server
> Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.6",
> GitCommit:"d921bc6d1810da51177fbd0ed61dc811c5228097",
> GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-27T17:44:26Z",
> GoVersion:"go1.16.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Helm version:

> version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.3.4",
> GitCommit:"a61ce5633af99708171414353ed49547cf05013d",
> GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.14.9"}

1. I have some common data that is used for both charts.

I want to use common data for both of the charts, event they do do not participate the same folders.

In `yaml` files something like:
`{{ include from specific common directory + file }}

2. In `values.yaml` file I need to add a dynamic variable, that is used in different attributes.

i.e. in the file:

```
mybasevar: "text"
myvariable: {{mybasevar}}-test

myvalue: {{ myvariable }}-tag1
myvalue2: {{ myvariable }}-tag2
```

In general, I didn't see an option for variables in `yaml` (maybe some *Go-Lang* code, or maybe this is basic on `yaml` files).

How can I the above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your message carefully and trying to understand what you want to achieve, I would advice to use Helm [Subcharts and Global Values](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/)

Let me explain. You could create your Chart (parent) which contains **componentA** and **componentB** as subcharts. In the  `Chart.yaml` of the parent chart, you would define the next dependencies:

```
dependencies:
    - name: componentA 
      version: "0.0.1"
      repository: "file://../componentA"
      condition: componentA.enabled
    - name: componentB 
      version: "0.0.1"
      repository: "file://../componentB"
      condition: componentB .enabled
```

At this point, you can deploy both components as a whole by using

```
helm install test parent/
```

Going back to your specific case:

> 1. I have some common data that is used for both charts.

Then, define it as global in the `values.yaml` of the parent chart. For example,

```
autoscaling:
  enabled: false
```

> 2. In values.yaml file I need to add a dynamic variable, that is used in different attributes.

In this case, add the name of the component in the `values.yaml` of the parent in the next way:

```
componentA:
  service:
    port: 80
componentB:
  service:
    port: 90
```

At this point, the variables will be dynamically filled in the subchart level. I think this approach would cover your needs nicely.

Comment: Thank you.

For 2 - What I meant is that I need a tag in values.yaml file like {{ basevalue }}, and use it in some lines in the values.yaml - can I do that? (Maybe the syntax is * or &... I don't know).